# Etch a sketch game, js file does not connect

Tags: javascript, html, css

Although I have no errors and the code seems fine the game etc a sketch does not even appear when I open in browser he index1 html, I double checked whether the connection with my js file is the issue. Why it does not appear in browser?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles1.css">
    <title>Etch-a-sketch game</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buttonDIV"></div>
<div id="container"></div>

</body>
<script src="main1.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --grid-cols: 1;
    --grid-rows: 1;
  }
  
  #container {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  }
  .grid-item {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

JavaScript

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {

  while(document.querySelector("button") !== null) {
    document.querySelector("button").remove();
  }

  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  container.style.width = "960px";
  container.style.overflow = "hidden";
 // console.log(container);
 // console.log(rows);
 // console.log(cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.style.minHeight ="0";
    cell.style.minWidth = "0";
    cell.style.overflow = "hidden";
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    cell.addEventListener("mouseover",()=> {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    })// makes thins black
    createButton();
};

function createButton() {
  const butonDiv = document.querySelector("#buttonDIV");
  const resetButton = document.createElement("button");
  resetButton.textContent = "reset grid!";
  resetButton.style.margin = "20px";
  butonDiv.appendChild(resetButton);

  resetButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item".forEach(e => {e.remove()}))

    let userGridinput = prompt("Please enter the number of grid squares(Max 100)");
    if(userGridinput > 100){
      alert("ERROR!Your grid size cannot be bigger han 100!");
      return
    };
    rows = userGridinput;
    cols = userGridinput;
    makeGrid(rows,cols);
      
    });
  };
}
```

please help me as I have gowned frustrated with this,

Comment: Learn how to use your browser's debugging tools: the console and the element tree first and foremost.

Comment: Looks like you're not actually calling your functions anywhere outside of the actual functions. You're also missing a } at the end of the makeGrid function

Comment: Your code consists primarily of a function. Which you never call.

Comment: Also be sure to declare your variables. Right now, your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)&nbsp;&mdash; for instance, you never declare `c` in your `for` loop in `makeGrid`. I suggest using strict mode for all new code, so that causes an error like it always should have. :-)